# Braintree - What to post for paymentMethodNonce

Tags: php, paypal, braintree

I am just getting started with Braintree and using it's API in PHP.

I have come across one thing, the "paymentMethodNouce" which is posted from the HTML file.

My question, is what does this need to include? I.e. do we post the send the credit card, billing information through here? And in what content does the form need to be in? I.e. Should it be like this:

```
    <form> 
      <input type="text" name="payment['creditcard']" value="124214124" />
      <input type="text" name"payment['billingaddress']" value="12312313"/>
   </form>
```

If this is not correct, what actually get's passed through to the `paymentMethodNonce` and how is the credit card details handled?

Answer (score 9):

Let me describe the procedure

**Payment method nonce**

The payment method nonce is a `string` returned by the client SDK to represent a payment method. This string is a reference to the **customer payment method details** that were provided in your payment form and should be sent to your server where it can be used with the server SDKs to create a new **transaction request**.

**To setup braintree**

1. First configure the environment and API credentials

   Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
   Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('use_your_merchant_id');
   Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('use_your_public_key');
   Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('use_your_private_key');
2. Get **client token** via ajax call from your server

   echo($clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());
3. Use client token returned from braintree to set up your form. Your form will be **visible** only if you have client token available.
4. Your form will now be rendering on your client. User fills in all info and submits the form.
5. If eveything went fine braintree will return **payment method nonce** for that user.
6. Store the **payment method nonce** on your server.

   $nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"]
7. Use that **payment method nonce** to perform the transaction in future.

   $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
         'amount' => '100.00',
         'paymentMethodNonce' => nonceFromTheClient
       ]);

Comment: when you press submit button from checkout form, how does it go to braintree server not to the web server?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [WitVault's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311077/braintree-what-to-post-for-paymentmethodnonce#35311700), you have several solutions to go from step 5 to 6. You can send it with an AJAX call or create a hidden input in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce">
```

And when your token is generated, set the latter as value of the input element then submit the form:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
      document.querySelector('input[name="payment_method_nonce"]').value = payload.nonce;
      form.submit();
   });
}, false);
```

Then step 6 will allow you to retrieve the token.